# How do you call a Meteor template helper from the console or other JS code?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I've defined a template helper in Meteor, say

```
Template.postsList.helpers({
  filteredPosts: function getPosts() {
    return Posts.find(...);
  }
});
```

How can I debug that template helper from the console, and how can I reuse it from other code in the app?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-helpers

Answer (score 7):

1. Wanting to call the helper from elsewhere in the app suggests that you should factor it out in a function.
2. To quickly debug the helper, evaluate this in the client console:

   ```
   Template.postsList.__helpers.get('filteredPosts')(...parameters);
   ```
3. There is a package that might help with debugging templates and template helpers: [prasad19sara:client-debugger](https://atmospherejs.com/prasad19sara/client-debugger).

Comment: How do I access global helpers?

Comment: @Kostanos UI._globalHelpers.yourHelperName(...parameters) to call UI.registerHelper('yourHelperName', function () {})

Answer (score 3):

It does not formally answer the question but I would like to share a simple technique, which virtually solves most of the problems you described.

Let's say we have a group of helpers, which we want to be able to access from different parts of your application both from templates and directly from our javascript code. To achieve that, I would have a global `Helpers` object, to which I could attach as many function as I want, e.g.

```
Helpers.routeIs = function (name) {
  var current = Router.current();
  return current && current.route && current.route.getName() === name;
};

Helpers.year = function () {
  return moment().year();
};
```

This makes them easily accessible throughout the code and pretty easy to test as well. But I also want to use them in my Spacebars templates, right?

A simple idea is to create a single global helper that would return the `Helpers` object itself.

```
Template.registerHelper('$', function () {
  return Helpers;
});
```

The nice thing about this is that it will enforce me to prefix each reference to my "global helper" with `$`, i.e. `{{$.year}}` or `{{$.routeIs 'home'}}`, which makes the code a lot more readable.

Unfortunately, there's a small problem with that solution. Consider the following example:

```
Helpers.fullName = function () {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};
```

The problem is that if my helper is about to access the current context through `this`, it will get the `Helpers` object itself rather than the data context, so the `{{$.fullName}}` will never work properly. But of course, there's a workaround for that:

```
Template.registerHelper('$', function () {
  return new Proxy(this);
});

function Proxy (context) {
  this.context = context;
}

// put this in a place when you're quite sure
// all the helpers are already defined

_.each(Helpers, function (helper, name) {
  Proxy.prototype[name] = function () {
    return helper.apply(this.context, arguments);
  };
});
```

## EDIT

I've added a reference implementation here:

https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-helpers

Comment: Nice pattern! Would be a nice addition to [ostrio:templatehelpers](https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/templatehelpers) or [aldeed:template-extension](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/template-extension).

Comment: Thanks! It's also very useful. I've tested in several projects and it really helps to make things organized.