# Using console to access Meteor Template.name.helpers functions

Tags: debugging, meteor

In a Meteor application, suppose I have the following template:

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  helper1: function () {
    alert("helper function called")
  }
}
```

How do I call the `helper1` function from the browser console?

---

EDIT: This is one solution:

```
Template.templateName.__helpers[" helper1"]()
```

Is there a more orthodox way?

Comment: Great question. I tried the above code and it works. However I was wondering why the space in " helper1" is necessary?

Comment: My guess is that this is done deliberately to prevent you from using `Template.templateName.__helpers.helper1()`, because you're not supposed doing this in production.

Comment: Makes sense. I am able to call a global helper with `UI._globalHelpers['userProfileInfo'](Meteor.userId())` from the browser console, where `userProfileInfo` is defined as `Template.registerHelper('userProfileInfo', function (userId) {`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you call a Meteor template helper from the console or other JS code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042886/how-do-you-call-a-meteor-template-helper-from-the-console-or-other-js-code)

Comment: This problem is already covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042886/how-do-you-call-a-meteor-template-helper-from-the-console-or-other-js-code/32045085#32045085